# Let's go as a question?

Tags: phrase-usage, modal-verbs, questions

Let's say my roommates and I are planning to go to place X, and they are waiting for me to get dressed.

After getting dressed, I might say something like this:

> Dude I am ready, let's go.

What I want to say is:

> Dude I am ready, should we go now?

Can **let's go** be used in the second expression in **should we go**?

Comment: Not if you want to ask it in the form of a question. "Let's go" is more of a declaration – perhaps exclamation, even – than a question.

Comment: I'd go even farther than @J.R.: an injunction.

Comment: Isn’t “Let’s go” an imperative?

Comment: Thor, if you are satisfied with the answer, accept it. If it is useful, vote it up. If it is not useful, vote it down.

Answer (score 2):

*Let* is used to make suggestions, as in "Let's go to the beach."
Another way to make suggestions is using *shall*, as in "Shall we go now?"

If you want to make it sound as a question, you can use *shall*.

*Should* is used for giving or asking for advice.

> You should stop thinking of her.

> Should I answer to the phone when I see it's her calling me?